# finalizer is not executing when deleting CR object

Tags: ansible, openshift

I am implementing use case for creating VM ,getting VM information from cloud.
To achieve this I have created separate playbook and role using operator-sdk api command.
For create VM I have created below playbook (vmcreate.yml)

```
---
- name: Create VM
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: false
  gather_facts: no
  collections:
    - kubernetes.core
    - operator_sdk.util

  vars:
    
    desired_state: present

  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: "vmcreate"
```

Role **vmcreate** contains below task to create VM and delete CR object after successful creation of VM

```
---
- name: VM creation
  block:  
  - name: Create VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: myResourceGroup
      name: win-vm
      vm_size: Standard_DS1_v2
      admin_username: azureuser
      admin_password: "{{ password }}"
      network_interfaces: nic
      os_type: Windows
      image:
          offer: WindowsServer
          publisher: MicrosoftWindowsServer
          sku: 2019-Datacenter
          version: latest
    no_log: true
    register: output_result
  - name: Remove the VM create CR
    k8s:
      state: absent
      api_version: vm-operator.example.com/v1
      kind: VmCreate
      name: "{{ ansible_operator_meta.name }}"
      namespace: "{{ ansible_operator_meta.namespace }}"
  
  rescue:
  - name: Error occurred during VM creation
    debug:
      msg: 'An error occurred during VM creation.\r\n {{ output_result | d("") }} \r\n Please check error logs for more detail.'
```

For getting VM information I have created separate playbook and separate task under **vmcreate** role.

playbook to create object (crobjcreate.yml)

```
---
- name: Create CR object
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: false
  gather_facts: no
  collections:
    - kubernetes.core
    - operator_sdk.util
  tasks:
    - name: Print Message
      debug:
        msg: "In crobjcreate.yml playbook"

    - name: Execute create CR object task
      import_tasks: "roles/tasks/providers/azure/cr-create.yml"
```

task created as **cr-create.yml**

```
---
- name: Create the CR for getting VM Information
  k8s:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: vm-operator.example.com/v1
      kind: VmGetInfo
      metadata:
        name: "myResourceGroup-win-vm"
        namespace: "{{ ansible_operator_meta.namespace}}"
      spec:
        cloud_provider: azure
        name: azure
        provideroptions:
          resource_group: myResourceGroup
  register: result
```

In watches.yml I used finalizer which expected to create Cr object to get vm information after deleting vmcreate CR object.
Below is the **watches.yml**

```
- version: v1
  group: vm-operator.example.com
  kind: VmCreate
  playbook: playbooks/vmcreate.yml
  snakeCaseParameters: false
  reconcilePeriod: 5s
  watchDependentResources: false
  finalizer:
    name: finalizer.vm-operator.example.com
    playbook: /opt/ansible/playbooks/crobjcreate.yml
```

When I am deploying this It is creating VM and deleting **vmcreate** CR object after successful creation of VM but it is not creating CR object to get vm information.
I am not sure what I am missing in this scenario.
Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to create objects before deletion of parent object.
However the problem was finalizer lock was not invoked after deletion of vmcreate Cr object. So I did changes in the play book which I called in finalizer block and it worked. I did below changes in playbook

```
---
- name: Create CR object
  hosts: all
  #connection: local
  #become: false
  #gather_facts: no
  #collections:
  #  - kubernetes.core
  #  - operator_sdk.util
  tasks:
    - name: Print Message
      debug:
        msg: "In crobjcreate.yml playbook"

    - name: Execute create CR object task
      import_tasks: "roles/tasks/providers/azure/cr-create.yml"
```

It worked for me.
However creation of object is not possible in this case because createVM CR object become parent object for VmGetInfo CR and whenever Parent get deleted garbage collector also removes the dependent CR.
So I change the logic of removing those CRs programmatically and let consumer program delete parent CR after VM deletion initiated by it